# Issue with converting a pandas column from int64 to datetime64

Tags: python, pandas, int64, datetime64

I'm trying to convert a column of Year values from int64 to datetime64 in pandas. The column currently looks like

```
         Year

         2003
         2003
         2003
         2003
         2003
         ... 
         2021
         2021
         2021
         2021
         2021
```

However the data type listed when I use `dataset['Year'].dtypes` is `int64`.

That's after I used `pd.to_datetime(dataset.Year, format='%Y')` to convert the column from int64 to datetime64. How do I get around this?

Comment: Which pandas version du you have? This should work

Comment: @mozway, I'm using pandas 1.4.3 . I was pretty confused myself as to why dataset['Year].dtypes was still showing int64.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to assign `pd.to_datetime(df['Year'], format="%Y")` to `df['date']`. Once you have done that you should be able to see convert from integer.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'Year': [2000,2000,2000,2000,2000,2000]})

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Year'], format="%Y")

df
```

The output should be:

```py
    Year    date
0   2000    2000-01-01
1   2000    2000-01-01
2   2000    2000-01-01
3   2000    2000-01-01
4   2000    2000-01-01
5   2000    2000-01-01
```

So essentially all you are missing is `df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Year'], format="%Y")` from your code and it should be working fine with respect to converting.

The `pd.to_datetime()` will not just return the Year (as far as I understood from your question you wanted the year), if you want more information on what `.to_date_time()` returns, you can see the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html).

I hope this helps.

Comment: It should be working if you have assigned the output. @mozway had a similar answer to mine so I believe his way would have worked too.

Comment: Looks like it's working now! I assigned it first to dataset['Year'], and now it's properly converting. Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to convert from an integer:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Year': [2003, 2022]})

df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Year'], format='%Y')

print(df)
```

Output:

```
   Year   datetime
0  2003 2003-01-01
1  2022 2022-01-01
```

Comment: Could it maybe be that the data was originally read from a csv file? The stuff I have in the question is how the Year column prints out for me, and when I checked the data type before trying anything, it was showing that the values int64, just like it's showing me now after using to_datetime. Maybe I'm missing something that's preventing to_datetime from working (white spaces I'm not seeing, missing values, etc.)?

Comment: Can you show your full code? Did you assign the output?

Comment: Good point! I'm gonna see if I can edit the question to include the whole code. Could be something I'm doing elsewhere causing this.

Comment: Actually, tweaked something from @Nameer1811 and it looks like it's working now. Thank you both for helping me understand pandas better! I really appreciate it!

Comment: OK, so you just had forgotten to assign? ;)

Comment: Looks like it, @mozway! It's the little things, right?